# Easy way to clean up OS X system files

Tags: macos, install

Is there an easy way (without completely formatting the disc) to clean all the files in the system folders like bin etc and just leave the needed ones? Different pythons installations like anaconda and playing around with brew or macports left a lot of unneeded files and different versions of different libraries.

Would a repair installation do this?

Comment: It wont touch your files, only repair os x files.

Answer (score 1):

Macports and Fink are well behaved and put all their stuff in /opt and /sw respectively. Delete those folders and you're done.

Other packages like to use /usr/local, the unix standard for, well, local only installations.

If something is being messy and putting files in */bin, /System, /Library etc. your options are to manually remove things or reinstall the system

Comment: Macports can have other traces (lots of other traces). See [Uninstalling MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html "Uninstalling MacPorts"), which I believe may not be accurate as to receipts which as of 10.8 are in a database, requiring resorting to using `pkgutil`, which can `pkgutil --pkgs=org.macports.\*` and forget `them. See the pkgutil man page.  You'll find you are in rich Macports receipt environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reinstalling OS X will replace all system folders with their default state, leaving all of your files in your home directory alone.

Comment: However this won't remove macports, homebrew or anaconda